# Data bound DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have a field 'oStatus' which I set as a List Box Value List in MS Access, with row source: Cancelled; Ordering; Pending; Processing and I have configured my DropDownList control to the data source.

However when i click on the drop down in my webpage, the control only shows the field's result (Eg. Ordering). How can i can i get it to show other items in the dropdownlist as well? (Cancelled, Pending, Processing, etc.)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runa4="server" 
                        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource7" DataTextField="oStatus" 
                        DataValueField="oStatus">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource7" runat="server" 
                       DataFile="~/App_Data/DB.mdb" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [oStatus] FROM [ordersTable] WHERE (oOrderNo = ?)">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="oOrderNo" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

MS Access

Field: oStatus

Row Source Type: Value List

Row Source: Cancelled;Ordering;Pending;Processing

Comment: Perhaps i didn't phrased my question correctly but I would like the dropdownlist control to contain Cancelled; Ordering; Pending etc. regardless of the field's value in the DB

Comment: Are you saying that your datasource only has "Ordering" and you want to add the other values to the datasource?  Will the other values ever come from the datasource or do you only need to add them when they are not there?

Comment: Yes, I would like the drop down list to show the value of the field but clicking on the drop down list will show other options (cancelled, etc.) as well. Would like it work as how it works in MS Access.

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you have at the moment (rather than vague statements) it is **impossible** to give you an answer to your problem

Comment: @user1166862 - did you find a solution to your issue? Was it as suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you are using the **single status for the order** as the datasource - meaning you will only ever get a single item in your dropdown.  In other words, the query you have written will only ever return a single item (because the row can only hold a single value).

You should populate the dropdown with all possible options, and then select the item which matches the status in the order.  Unfortunately I do not know how you would do that with the `<asp:AccessDataSource>` control, as I've never used it.

The options should be populated either statically...

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server">
  <asp:ListValue value="1">Cancelled</asp:ListValue>
  ...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or if they are values in the database, then I guess you use the `<asp:AccessDataSource>` to populate them, and then use another method to select the correct one based on the value in the `ordersTable`.